# PySpark is not able to comprehend any data file into dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I am getting a strange error since past few days and not able to solve this issue.

1. I am using pyspark and trying to load csv to DF [code below] it gives the same error :

   ```
    py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o10.textFile.
   : java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field transient java.lang.Object[]
   ```
2. I actually wanted to convert the csv to parquet initially, and even this is resulting in the same error. ( It converts to parquet successfully, but when I try to print the schema OR count of some column in this table, it fails with the same error as above)

Code for csv to Df:

```
    from pyspark import SparkContext
    from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
    from pyspark.sql.types import *
    import os
    os.environ['SPARK_HOME']="/opt/apps/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/"


    from pyspark import SQLContext
    sc = SparkContext(master='local')
    sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)


    Employee_rdd = sc.textFile("abc.csv").map(lambda line: line.split(","))
    Employee_df = Employee_rdd.toDF()
    Employee_df.show()
```

Error stacktrace:

```
    File "/home/v/scripts/g_s_pipe/a.py", line 14, in 
        Employee_rdd = sc.textFile("abc.csv").map(lambda line: line.split(","))
      File "/opt/apps/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py", line 476, in textFile
        return RDD(self._jsc.textFile(name, minPartitions), self,
      File "/opt/apps/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
      File "/opt/apps/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
        return f(*a, **kw)
      File "/opt/apps/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
    py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o10.textFile.
    : java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field transient java.lang.Object[] java.util.ArrayList.elementData accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @51b63e70
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:335)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:278)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:175)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:169)
```

Code for csv to parquet :

```
    import os
    os.environ['SPARK_HOME']="/opt/apps/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/"

    from pyspark import SparkContext
    from pyspark.sql import functions as F
    from pyspark.sql import *
    from pyspark.sql.types import *
    sc = SparkContext(master='local')

    sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)


    df= sqlContext.read.parquet("tract_alpha.parquet")
    print (df.count())
```

It also gives the same error :

```
    17/06/12 21:17:21 WARN BlockManager: Putting block broadcast_1 failed due to an exception
    17/06/12 21:17:21 WARN BlockManager: Block broadcast_1 could not be removed as it was not found on disk or in memory
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/vna/scripts/global_score_pipeline/test_code_here.py", line 62, in 
        print (df.count())
      File "/opt/apps/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 299, in count
        return int(self._jdf.count())
      File "/opt/apps/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
      File "/opt/apps/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
        return f(*a, **kw)
      File "/opt/apps/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
    py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o25.count.
    : java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field transient java.lang.Object[] java.util.ArrayList.elementData accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @5e37932e
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:335)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:278)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:175)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:169)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$$anonfun$getClassInfo$3.apply(SizeEstimator.scala:336)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$$anonfun$getClassInfo$3.apply(SizeEstimator.scala:330)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$.getClassInfo(SizeEstimator.scala:330)
```

What is this InaccessibleObject exception, I am not finding much help regarding this on Google and how to resolve this??

Comment: It will not help you understand the problem with Spark but if you only want to convert a file from CSV to Apache Parquet you could use Pandas and Apache Arrow (the python package is called pyarrow) http://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/ and skip the Java stack for that part.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to Arrow. but i have created a Small example parquet using arrow and still it is not able to read even this parquet... I get the same error, what can be wrong here?